# Is it possible to block .exe with a certain Company/File Description/Size from being run on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

Is it possible to block .exe with a certain Company/File Description/Size from being run on Windows?

Basically trying to block this one file, but the end user could rename the file, and I don't want to block *all* exe's. Not looking for a completely foolproof solution, just enough of a deterrent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with an AppLocker policy in a Group Policy Object (GPO).

> 1. Click Start, type local security policy, and then click **Local Security Policy**.
> 2. If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click **Yes**.
> 3. In the console tree of the snap-in, double-click **Application Control Policies**, double-click **AppLocker**, and then click the
>    rule collection that you want to create the rule for.

Source: [Administer AppLocker on the local PC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/administer-applocker#bkmk-using-snapins)

In order to create the AppLocker rule itself:

> 1. Open the AppLocker console, and then click the rule collection that you want to create the rule for.
> 2. On the Action menu, click **Create New Rule**.
> 3. On the Before You Begin page, click **Next**.
> 4. On the Permissions page, select the action (**allow** or **deny**) and the user or group that the rule should apply to, and then click
>    **Next**.
> 5. On the Conditions page, select the **Publisher** rule condition, and then click Next.
> 6. On the Publisher page, click **Browse** to select a signed file, and then use the slider to specify the scope of the rule. To use
>    custom values in any of the fields or to specify a specific file
>    version, select the Use custom values check box. For example, you can
>    use the asterisk (*) wildcard character within a publisher rule to
>    specify that any value should be matched. Click **Next**.
> 7. (Optional) On the Exceptions page, specify conditions by which to exclude files from being affected by the rule. Click Next.
> 8. On the Name page, either accept the automatically generated rule name or type a new rule name, and then click **Create**

Source: [Create a rule that uses a publisher condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/create-a-rule-that-uses-a-publisher-condition)